# insert data form to database with special character

Tags: php, mysql

I have the form as i want; Can you help me to insert sent data in Databases? this is the form  [jsfiddle.net/AbuNidal/Rqt5u/9](http://jsfiddle.net/AbuNidal/Rqt5u/9) my process_form.php

```
<?php 
$title=$_POST['title'];
$catid=$_POST['catid'];
$published='1';
$introtext=$_POST['text'];
$created='155';
$access='1';
$language='*';
$publish_down='0000-00-00 00:00:00';
$language=$_POST['[{"id":"4","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_4']"},{"id":"6","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_6']"},{"id":"12","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_12']"},{"id":"13","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_13']"},{"id":"7","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_7']"},{"id":"8","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_8']"},{"id":"9","value":"K2ExtraField_9"},{"id":"1","value":"K2ExtraField_1"},{"id":"2","value":"K2ExtraField_2"},{"id":"3","value":"K2ExtraField_3"},{"id":"5","value":"K2ExtraField_5"},{"id":"10","value":["","http:\/\/$_POST['K2ExtraField_10']","new"]},{"id":"11","value":["","http:\/\/$_POST['K2ExtraField_11']","new"]}]'];


$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("form", $con);

$query("INSERT INTO y2ium_items ( title, catid, published, introtext, extra_fields, created, publish_down, access, language)
VALUES (null,'$title',$catid,$published,'$introtext','$extra_fields',$created,$publish_down,$access,$language)");
$result=mysql_query($query,$con);
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

thank you

Comment: 1. Why don't you `echo $query;` before you submit it? 2. Stop using `mysql_` functions. They are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql). Use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: what is with the $language=$_POST[...] part? That's assigning it to a  surely non existent key of the $_POST array.

Comment: sorry i am a user of CMS JOOMLA! and this table for K2 component, i am only trying to make form for insert my data.

Comment: What is not working? Does the insert fail? does the connection fail?

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
[{"id":"4","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_4']"},{"id":"6","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_6']"},{"id":"12","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_12']"},{"id":"13","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_13']"},{"id":"7","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_7']"},{"id":"8","value":"$_POST['K2ExtraField_8']"},{"id":"9","value":"K2ExtraField_9"},{"id":"1","value":"K2ExtraField_1"},{"id":"2","value":"K2ExtraField_2"},{"id":"3","value":"K2ExtraField_3"},{"id":"5","value":"K2ExtraField_5"},{"id":"10","value":["","http:\/\/$_POST['K2ExtraField_10']","new"]},{"id":"11","value":["","http:\/\/$_POST['K2ExtraField_11']","new"]}]
```

Looks like JSON.  Try using json_decode.  That should get you going.  And don't use mysql_* functions, as stated in comments above.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php